# Correct MVC approach for UITableViewCell updating model?

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller

I'm fairly new to MVC and I have a question regarding models and views. I have some content views that allow users to favorite that content with a tap. This happens in the view and I need to update the data model with the new information. It seems to me the easy approach would be to have a `Note` property on each cell and then when that cell was tapped in the controller I could call `addFavoriteNote` or `removeFavoriteNote` on the `DataSource` using the note associated with that cell. However, `Note` is a class from the model, so it is my understanding that it would be incorrect to have a `Note` property in the `UITableViewCell`. Is this wrong in MVC and if so what is an MVC-oriented approach?

```
class Note: Comparable {
var content: String!
var creationDate: Date!
var author: Person!
init(content: String, creationDate: Date, author: Person) {
    self.content = content
    self.author = author
    self.creationDate = creationDate
}
convenience init(author: Person) {
    self.init(content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed in efficitur nulla. Suspendisse facilisis tincidunt dictum. Praesent bibendum efficitur lectus vitae imperdiet. Sed odio est, fermentum et turpis vel, pellentesque volutpat magna. Aliquam iaculis libero at dignissim rutrum. Phasellus luctus elementum eros, gravida consequat tellus dignissim ultricies. Ut consectetur ut ante imperdiet molestie. Aliquam blandit, nulla eu egestas accumsan, diam justo varius augue, vel pellentesque felis tortor in orci. In nunc erat, luctus a mauris in, molestie blandit lorem. Vestibulum cursus, ligula sed lobortis vulputate, mauris eros finibus dui, id pretium lacus tortor eu erat. Curabitur pretium, ante in pellentesque vehicula, metus quam interdum leo, faucibus facilisis tellus massa a turpis. Pellentesque sit amet est sem. Vestibulum posuere luctus libero pretium faucibus", creationDate: Date(), author: author)
}
static func <(lhs: Note, rhs: Note) -> Bool {
    return lhs.creationDate < rhs.creationDate
}

static func ==(lhs: Note, rhs: Note) -> Bool {
    return lhs.creationDate == rhs.creationDate
}
}

class DataSource: NSObject {
private var favorites: [Note] = []

func addFavoriteNote(note: Note) {
    favorites.append(note)
}

func removeFavoriteNote(note: Note) {
    if let index = favorites.index(of: note) {
        favorites.remove(at: index)
    }
}

//...more stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that you should not have the cell update the model. Your cell should notify the view controller of the event of checking/unchecking. This would be implemented using a delegate pattern or using a closure. The view controller would be the delegate or provide the closure that is called when the event takes place in the cell. As the controller, the view controller can handle this event by updating the model as needed.

A controller provides the view (cell in this case) with just enough data to display itself.

A controller handles events from views (such as a cell) that result in the model being updated.

The controller handles model events and tells views to update based on updated data.

Comment: I understand all that. My specific question is how do I figure out which note from the model corresponds to the cell that was clicked? I need to somehow associate the text box values in the cell with a `Note` object and remove that note from the favorites list in the model.

Comment: The cell would pass itself as an argument to the delegate method or closure. The view controller can then ask the table view what indexPath the cell is associated with. From the indexPath, the controller can get the needed data from the model just as it does in the `cellForRowAt` method.

Comment: Thanks! So like a dictionary with IndexPaths and Data?

Comment: Probably not. Typically you have an array of data for your table view's data model.

Comment: What if the model data is modified (i.e. new data received) and the data in the ViewController array does not line up with the model?

Comment: This is getting well beyond the scope of the question but in general, the view controller needs to create/update whatever data model the table needs based on the full model.